# QGIS clip vector layer to current map extent

Tags: qgis, clip, extents

I wonder if there is a way to simply clip a vector layer in QGIS (2.14.1) to the current map extent.

Clipping algorithm needs another 'clipper' vector layer as input and 'save as...' saves a vector layer restricted to the current extent but does not clip. I think it might be not too difficult to write a plugin to accomplish it - and I certainly will, if there is no simple way that I might have missed to do this.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In the *Processing Toolbox*, you can use the **Clip vectors by extent** tool from GDAL/OGR:

`Processing Toolbox > GDAL/OGR > [OGR] Geoprocessing > Clip vectors by extent`

Comment: Knew I was missing something... But this seems not to work properly though. I need to clip a parcel layer (postgis, polygons). Leaving the 'clip boundaries' field in the dialog empty results in a copy of the layer (memory layer), and selecting a clip rectangle from canvas or use canvas extent for clipping results in an empty line-layer (temporary layer or shapefile doesn't matter).

Comment: @JochenSchwarze - Sorry, can't create a PostGIS layer to test it at the moment.

Comment: Then it solved this question for the moment. Gonna start another one for the clipping issue.